# How do I get my new BIRT 4.3.1 to use the use the same project and workspace for everything I built in 4.2.1?

Tags: upgrade, birt

All of the following is done in a cloned development (VM) server, so there is no risk to my production environments (prd04 for completed reports, tst04 for creation and problem solving, working on clone of tst04 now).

I have been using BIRT 4.2.1 for a  about a year, I have several reports and most importantly a library that were created with 4.2.1.  While the production reports actually run via Apache, I have downloaded and updated the "runtime" files so any new reports will run ok, but this made 95% of the old reports stop working.  It does not make sense to try and “fix” them with 4.2.1 if I am going to be running 4.3.1 now.  I expect the problem to be fixed with a library correction related to jar or war file.

I want to use my fresh download of 4.3.1 in the same workspace and with the same project as I used for 4.2.1.  But I am days into trying to make it work and no luck.

Failures

- Tried to upgrade the existing 4.2.1 to 4.3.1 but [never got it to work correctly](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/31291-how-to-update-birt/#entry123146)

  - Ended up downloading a fresh copy, so now I have two instances of BIRT (one of each)
  - Used the existing 4.2.1 workspace for 4.3.1 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\Birt
- Brought in the Navigator View, but am unable to make it “see” the existing reports and projects
- Project > Open Project will not work, “Open Project” is greyed out.  If I create a new project “open project” and “close project” works but still can’t “see” my existing project
- Open an existing report and try to “save as” in the workspace, but it can’t see …Tomcat 7.0\webapps\Birt
- Try to drag (project, library, report) and drop from Resources to Navigator Does not work
- Try to drag (project, library, report) and drop from the Window file to Navigator Does not work
- Looked into “CVS Repositories” but at first glance it does not seem to be the correct path.
- Tried a bunch of other things, but they did not work and were not as promising as the above.

It is starting to feel like I only have two options left;

1. Create a separate Apache instance for running any new 4.3.1 reports, leaving all the existing reports running on Apache with the 4.2.1 “runtime" files
2. Create a new project for 4.3.1 and one by one rebuild existing reports, once I have everything working upgrade my production Apache and redeploy all the updated reports.

Screen shot of invisible workspace 
[image: WorkSpace]

Comment: This question is also posted at [BIRT Developer Center](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/31379-how-do-i-get-my-new-birt-431-to-use-the-use-the-same-project-and-workspace-for-everything-i-built-in-421/)

Answer (score 2):

Your wrote: I have downloaded and updated the "runtime" files so any new reports will run ok, but this made 95% of the old reports stop working.

What exactly do you mean? Error messages? Hangs? Crashes? OutOfMemoryError?

If it's OOM you probably hit a "feature" introduced in 4.2.2 regarding Default Row Fetch Size (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407299).

Apart from that, I don't see a reason why any report created with 4.2.1 should not run with 4.3.

And just to clarify: Are you using an Eclipse IDE as a kind of "BIRT Reports Server" somehow? To be honest, that sounds crazy.

We are also using a custom plugin. This was developed with BIRT 3.7.1 and runs on 3.7.1, 4.2.1 and 4.3 without any problems.

The same is true for the BIRT runtime Environment (bunch of JARs, no OSGI). We are not using Apache Tomcat (instead we developed a "BIRT Reports Server").

It should be possible to update the Tomcat Server by just replacing the 4.2.1 JARs with 4.3 JARs and setting the classpath accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  But you are focusing on the symptoms that I would like to address after getting an answer to using the same workspace for 4.2.1 & 4.3.1.  I suspect that a "library correction related to jar or war file", but first I would like to get both versions of BIRT using the same project space.  If I am going to need to move all the reports and librarys to a new workspace to use 4.3.1 there is no point in working towards a solution with 4.2.1

Comment: I think that "updating" the IDE is not going to work. But is that really a problem? Just create a second workspace with 4.3.1. and copy the BIRT project. The only work to do is to configure the 4.3.1 IDE (class-path, custom plugins, settings, ...). You should document this configuration anyway. And use a version control system like SVN, GIT or ... as a repository for your reports.

Comment: I am going down that path now, on review it looks like some of the issues may have been related to working on server that was a clone.